# callback for createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to share image and text to different apps on the mobile. I have created an `IntentChooser` to select app to share the content with and a `Broadcast Receiver` to get the callback on what the user clicked. Now problem is with Facebook. I want to share a hashtag but its not going through `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`. I have integrated `Facebook SDK` as well. I have added the `Broadcast Receiver` so that I can show `ShareDialog` of Facebook to share image and Hashtag. But when user pick Facebook from `createChooser` its opening the app and then giving callback to `Broadcast`.

How can I add `HashTag` to the post I share through Facebook ?

```
public void doSocialShare(String title, String text, Bitmap resource){

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getBitmapFromDrawable(resource));
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setType("image/*");

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            Log.d("INFORMATION", "The current android version allow us to know what app is chosen by the user.");

            Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(this,ShareBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            sendIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share via...", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

This is my Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ShareBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
        }
    }
}
```